# Why win32 thread doesn't exit automatically?

Tags: c++, multithreading, wcf, web-services

**Background:**

In my application written in C++, I create a worker thread which in turn creates two threads using [`CreateThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx). The two threads which worker thread creates, talk to WCF Service through a client which is implemented using [Windows Web Services API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd430435(v=vs.85).aspx) which offers C/C++ application programming interface (API) for building SOAP based web services and clients to them. My application implements *only* the client using this API.

**Problem:**

The problem I'm facing is that all other threads exit gracefully, except the worker thread, as you can see yourself, in the image below that `WorkerThreadProc` uses no CPU cycles yet it doesn't exit. There are also few other threads running which are not created by me, but by the runtime.

The thread states are as follows (as reported by [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795533)):

- `WorkerThreadProc` is in **Wait:WrUserRequest** state.
- `wWinMainCRTStartup` is in **Wait:UserRequest** state.
- All `TpCallbackIndependent` are in **Wait:WrQueue** state.

What are they waiting for? What could be possible causes that I need to look into? Also, what is the difference between *WrUserRequest* and *UserRequest*? And what does *WrQueue* mean? I've absolutely no idea what is going on here.

[image]

---

Here is my WorkerThreadProc code. I've removed all the logging statements except the last one at the bottom of the function:

```
DWORD WINAPI WorkerThreadProc(PVOID pVoid)
{

    //Initialize GDI+
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR           gdiplusToken;

    Status status = GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    if ( status != Status::Ok )
    {
        return 1;
    }

    GuiThreadData *pGuiData = (GuiThreadData*)pVoid;

    auto patternIdRequestQueue= new PatternIdRequestQueue();
    auto resultQueue = new ResultQueue();

    auto patternManager = new PatternManager(patternIdRequestQueue);
    LocalScheduler *pScheduler = new LocalScheduler(resultQueue, patternManager);

    bool bInitializationDone = pScheduler->Initialize(pGuiData->m_lpCmdLine);
    if ( !bInitializationDone )
    {
        return 0;
    }

    //PatternIdThread
    PatternIdThread patternIdThread(patternIdRequestQueue);
    DWORD dwPatternIdThreadId;
    HANDLE hPatternIdThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, PatternIdThreadProc, &patternIdThread, 0, &dwPatternIdThreadId);

    ResultPersistence resultPersistence(resultQueue);
    DWORD dwResultPersistenceThreadId;
    HANDLE hResultPersistenceThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ResultPersistenceThreadProc, &resultPersistence, 0, &dwResultPersistenceThreadId);

    pScheduler->ScheduleWork(pGuiData->m_hWnd, pGuiData->m_hInstance, ss.str());

    pScheduler->WaitTillDone();
    patternIdThread.Close();
    resultPersistence.Close();

    delete pScheduler; 

    //Uninitialize GDI+
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);

    dwRet = WaitForSingleObject(hPatternIdThread, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hPatternIdThread);

    dwRet = WaitForSingleObject(hResultPersistenceThread,INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hResultPersistenceThread);

    SendMessage(pGuiData->m_hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);

    //IMPORTANT : this verbose message is getting logged!
    T_VERBOSE(EvtSrcInsightAnalysis, 0, 0, "After sending message to destroy window");

    delete patternManager;
    delete patternIdRequestQueue;
    delete resultQueue;
    return 0;
}
```

Please see the `T_VERBOSE` macro, it is used to log verbose message. I see the message is getting logged, yet the thread doesn't exit!

---

EDIT:

I just commented the following line in my `WorkerThreadProc`, then worker thread exits gracefully!

```
SendMessage(pGuiData->m_hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
```

Does it mean that `SendMessage` is the culprit? Why would it block the thread the calling thread?

Comment: Are you calling CloseHandle() on the thread handle after it exits? You should use WaitForSingleObject() to wait for the thread to finish.

Comment: @infact: Of course, yes! And yes, I'm using `WaitForSingleObject` to wait for the thread to finish!

Comment: Why don't you use abstractions like `boost::thread` that are proven to work fine (and are even portable)?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I don't need portability. Also, do you mean win32 threads are bad (and proven to be so)? What does `boost::thread` use internally?

Comment: @Nawaz: No, I mean that they are obviously (your post is a good example) not very easy to use. And good wrappers like `boost::thread` are easier to use, and avoid certain pitfalls.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: What if I come up with topics asking questions regarding `boost::thread`? I find your argument weak.

Comment: Can you show some (maybe abstracted) code of what the thread is executing?

Comment: @Tudor: I posted the code of WorkerThreadProc.

Comment: Can you confirm that there are no points of indefinite blocking in this code and that execution reaches the end of the function successfully?

Comment: @Tudor: That is interesting and important question. I updated the posted code with a `T_VERBOSE` logging macro. Please see the `T_VERBOSE` macro in my code, it is used to log verbose message. I see the message is getting logged, yet the thread doesn't exit!

Comment: @Nawaz, you should add that as an answer not add it in your question.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant: What should I add as answer?

Comment: "I just commented the following line in my WorkerThreadProc, then worker thread exits gracefully!"

Comment: @Nawaz: What argument? I am just asking why you don't use it. If you have a proper reason, like, say, a wrapper does not provide some functionality you need, then all is fine. I am just thinking that the exact problem you have, and any other problems on the same level, would not arise since `boost::thread` does these things for you.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: What problem am I facing that can be avoided with `boost::thread`?

Comment: @Nawaz: For one, all the fiddling with the winapi you are doing here. For boost threads, there are two ways to let them end. Either you detach them and destroy the object (which means the os thread will completely destroyed after it exited itself), or you join the thread before destryoing the object (which means the os thread will die after joining). Not much room for the fiddling around with OS API you currently do...

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I understand that. But how does `boost::thread` provide those functionalities on windows? Are they not using win32 thread internally? If yes, then what am I doing wrong, is what I want to know. Also, as it seems, it is `SendMessage()` which is causing the problem, if so, then even `boost::thread` cannot help!

Comment: @Nawaz: Of course they use the winapi. The point here is that they do something similar to your code (probably, I dont know), but they do it right. and this is the reason why you should use libraries. they do it right, and you dont have to bother. you can go on and do the real work.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Is that the problem with my code? Or, you think I'm unaware of `boost::thread`?

Answer (score 3):

If we look at the docs for `SendMessage`, you can see this little quote:

> To send a message and return immediately, use the SendMessageCallback
>   or SendNotifyMessage function. To post a message to a thread's message
>   queue and return immediately, use the PostMessage or PostThreadMessage
>   function.

and this:

> Messages sent between threads are processed only when the receiving
>   thread executes message retrieval code. The sending thread is blocked
>   until the receiving thread processes the message. However, the sending
>   thread will process incoming nonqueued messages while waiting for its
>   message to be processed. To prevent this, use SendMessageTimeout with
>   SMTO_BLOCK set. For more information on nonqueued messages, see
>   Nonqueued Messages.

so from this we can see `SendMessage` will block till the message is processed, which may somehow lead to a deadlock in your code, as the msgproc doesn't reside in your worker thread, leading to a context switch (which is only triggered when the thread's queue is pumped for messages). Try using `PostMessage`, which immediately returns.

EDIT: there is also a nice little piece of info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#deadlocks) on message deadlocks from `SendMessage`

Comment: After finding out the problem with `SendMessage()` myself (as I posted this in my question), I read the doc (which you've posted as answer) on MSDN, but what I'm not getting is that why `SendMessage` doesn't return. It doesn't return means that the recieving thread doesn't process the messages, which in turns implies that if I use `PostMessage`, then it will not process the messages even then. Although, it will solve the problem of blocking the thread, but the real problem (which we *now* know) is still there, which is this : messages are not being processed!

Comment: @Nawaz: That part would be better solved using something like Spy++, I also faced a similar problem with `WM_CLOSE` messages not being processed, traced it back to another window message returning the wrong value, leading to the `WM_CLOSE` message being removed from the queue so it couldn't be processed